# Why is there no screen tearing at all on linux?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, tearing

I recently switched to Ubuntu as my primary OS(have been using ubuntu for a year but used windows primarily). I used a fix(https://www.cmscritic.com/how-to-fix-nvidia-screen-tearing-in-xfce-mate-kde-lxde-and-others/) for the screen tearing with nvidia cards and reduced the swappiness to 1(having 24gb ram). It worked out too perfectly as even with vsync off in every single game(CS:GO, Borderlands 2, Rise of the Tomb Raider) there is no screen tearing at all. I am curious to know why is that. I have been struggling with screen tearing on Windows with vsync off and I am never switching again to Windows.

Comment: What you ask has 1 simple answer: that is how it should work.  Mind that nobody here will be able to answer as you probably use the closed source nVidia driver. So it will be impossible to view the source code.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I think this question should be on nVidia forum or SuperUser at least were you may find experienced user from both platforms.